# Trying to use SSRS rsconfig.exe in silent mode to create the ReportServer and ReportServerTemp databases on a local instance

Tags: ssrs, automation, ssrs-2017

I have installed a brand new SQL 2017 Enterprise instance on a Windows 2019 Datacentre VM.

I have then installed SQL Server Reporting Services via the command line (/quiet, /norestart, etc) and all has installed fine.

I am able to use rsconfigtool.exe to manually create the ReportServer and ReportServerTemp databases via the GUI, but I would like to be able to complete this task via automation (if possibly silently and via the command line).

I would like to have the ReportServer and ReportServerTemp databases installed on the instance I have created and not a new SSRS instance.

rsconfigtool.exe does not appear to except any parameters in order to make this change.

Any advice/help would be gratefully received.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using the rsconfigtool.exe Gui application you can use [rsconfig.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/tools/rsconfig-utility-ssrs?view=sql-server-ver15) from the command line. It is located in the same Shared Tools directory. `rsconfig.exe /?` allows you to see the available command line arguments.

[image]